# Model override for regions not working

Tags: magento-1.9, module, overrides, country-regions

I'm trying to limit the states that show in the dropdown in the store.  I thought that overriding the _initSelect() method in the app/code/core/Mage/Directory/Model/Resource/Region/Collection.php would help do the trick.  Unfortunately, while the change works when applied to the original file, it doesn't work in the override.

Here's the relevant line in my config.xml:

```
<global>
    <models>
        <directory>
            <rewrite>
                <resource_region_collection>
                    Test_Test_Model_Directory_Resource_Region_Collection
                </resource_region_collection>
            </rewrite>
        </directory>
    </models>
</global>
```

Here's my version of the file in app/code/local/Test/Test/Model/Directory/Resource/Region/Collection.php:

```
<?php
class Test_Test_Model_Directory_Resource_Region_Collection extends Mage_Directory_Model_Resource_Region_Collection
{
    protected function _initSelect()
    {
        parent::_initSelect();
        $excludeRegions = array ('AS','AF','AA','AC','AE','AM','AP','FM','GU','MH','MP','PW','VI');
        $this->getSelect()->where('code NOT IN (?)', $excludeRegions);

        return $this;
    }
}
```

The "Test" module is working for other Magento overrides I have running, but for some reason isn't working for this one in particular.  Any thoughts or suggestions would be awesome, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resource models overwrites are not declared the same way as normal models you should replace:

```
<directory>
        <rewrite>
            <resource_region_collection>
                Test_Test_Model_Directory_Resource_Region_Collection
            </resource_region_collection>
        </rewrite>
    </directory>
```

with:

```
<directory_resource>
        <rewrite>
            <region_collection>
                Test_Test_Model_Directory_Resource_Region_Collection
            </region_collection>
        </rewrite>
    </directory_resource>
```

Comment: Thank you so much!  That was the answer, I didn't realize the declaration was different.  Thanks again!